# How to do recursive edit using SED or any other utility

Tags: unix, recursion, sed

I have a string as below:

```
set str = "A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,B,,,,,,,C,,,,,,,,,,D,,,,,,,,,,,,E"
```

I want to run a sed on it such that the final result is

```
"A,B,C,D,E"
```

I tried doing this using
`sed 's/,,/,/g'` 
but with this, it only halves the number of commas.

```
echo $str | sed 's/,,/,/g' == A,,,,,,,,B,,,,C,,,,,D,,,,,,E
```

Can you suggest a way that can give me $str_out is smaller/shorter commands?

Answer (score 3):

Change your sed command to,

```
sed 's/,\+/,/g'
```

In BRE `\+` would repeat the previous character one or more times. So `,\+` matches one or more commas. Replacing the matched commas with a single comma will give you the desired output.

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,B,,,,,,,C,,,,,,,,,,D,,,,,,,,,,,,E' | sed 's/,\+/,/g'
A,B,C,D,E
```

Comment: `sed 's/,\{2,\}/,/g` for posix version (`+` replace also 1 occurence by itself so maybe a `,,\+` (or `,,,*` for BRE and posix)

Comment: Both gives the same output.

Comment: hopefully, it was just a CPU "load" and posix compliance remarq, your sed was already simple and good

Comment: An alternative is `sed 's/,,*/,/g' file` which reads replace a `,` and zero or more `,`'s with a `,`.

Comment: in this case `sed 's/,,,*/,/g' YourFile` to only change when at least 2 `,`are present

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
$ echo 'A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,B,,,,,,,C,,,,,,,,,,D,,,,,,,,,,,,E' | tr -s ','
A,B,C,D,E
```

or

```
$ echo 'A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,B,,,,,,,C,,,,,,,,,,D,,,,,,,,,,,,E' | tr -s ',' ' '
A B C D E
```